# div hover background color with textarea inside

Tags: css, html, textarea

I have a `textarea` inside a `div`. The `textarea` is almost the same as the size of the `div`, leaving only a narrow strip of the `div` around it visible. What I want to achieve ( preferrably with CSS only) is have the background of the `div` change when the mouse cursor is on it, but not when it is over the `textarea`. In other words, if the mouse cursor is on top of the visible `div` strip around the textarea, I want the `div` `background color` to change, but if it is on top of the textarea itself I do not want it to change

Here is a jsfiddle that illustrates the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/TS98t/

HTML:

```
<div class="mydiv">
    <textarea class="mytextarea"></textarea>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.mydiv {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: green;
}

.mydiv:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}

.mytextarea {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    resize: none;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

The `div` is green the `textarea` is yellow. If i move the mouse over the div it becomes blue. But I don't want it to become blue when the mouse is over the `textarea`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Impossible with current implementations of CSS :( Use JavaScript to change color onhover (with `event.stopPropagation()` )

Comment: $('.mytextarea').mouseover(function() {
  $('this').parent().css('background-color', 'green');

});

Comment: nothing is impossible.....

Comment: if you break impossible ....its i m possible

Comment: @khan: this is impossible with CSS only; of course you can do it easily with JS :)

Comment: may be you are right...........

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Selectors Level 4 allows this via the [Determining the Subject of a Selector](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#subject) syntax:

```
.mydiv {
    background-color: green;
}

.mydiv:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}

!.mydiv textarea:hover {
    background-color: green;
}
```

… but that specification is currently a very early draft and I'd be surprised if there was any browser support for it at all.

Until that, you will need to look to JavaScript for this. For example:

```
.mydiv.textarea_hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

and

```
var t = document.querySelector('textarea');
var d = t.parentNode;
t.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
    d.className += " textarea_hover";
});
t.addEventListener('mouseout', function () {
    d.className = d.className.replace(/ textarea_hover/g, "");
});
```

Comment: +1 for using pure JS, as the question does not mention jQuery

Comment: @KeesSonnema — Please be more specific. What do you think I've missed?